# How to join entity with relation using query annotation in SpringBoot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

**1. This is the user entity that belongs to "users" table**

```
public class UserEntity implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String email;

    private String password;

    private String firstName;

    private String lastName;

    private String profileImage;

    @UpdateTimestamp
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date updatedAt;
}
```

**2. This is the Customer Entity**

```
public class CustomerEntity extends AbstractEntity{
    @Id
    private String customerId;

    @Column(length = 200)
    private String name;

    private String email;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private UserEntity userEntity;

}
```

**3. And this is the payment entity**

```
public class PaymentEntity extends AbstractEntity{
    @Id
    private String id;

    @Column(length = 200)
    private String record;

    private Integer amount;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id")
    private CustomerEntity customerEntity;
}
```

I want to join these 3 entities, using query annotation, and I am using like that

```
@Query(value = "SELECT U.firstName,U.lastName,P.amount FROM" +
            " UserEntity as U JOIN CustomerEntity as C ON C.userEntity" +
            " JOIN PaymentEntity as P ON P.customerEntity" +
            " WHERE (U.email like %:search%) OR (U.firstName like %:search%) OR" +
            " (U.lastName like %:search%) ORDER BY U.updatedAt")
```

*But this is not working, and give an error. Any idea how to do that.*

Comment: Share the error details

Comment: <AST>:1:167: unexpected AST node: .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this and fetch using UserEntity repository you will get all related customer and payment enitity

##### user entity

```
public class UserEntity implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String email;

    private String password;

    private String firstName;

    private String lastName;

    private String profileImage;

    @UpdateTimestamp
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date updatedAt;
    
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private List<CustomerEntity> customerEntities;
}
```

##### Customer Entity

```
public class CustomerEntity extends AbstractEntity{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long customerId;

    @Column(length = 200)
    private String name;

    private String email;

    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private Long userId;
    
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id", referencedColumnName = "customerId")
    private List<PaymentEntity> paymentEntities;

}
```

##### payment entity

```
public class PaymentEntity extends AbstractEntity{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(length = 200)
    private String record;

    private Integer amount;

    @Column(name = "customer_id")
    private Long customerId;
}
```